# Apache Multiple instances without specifying the port in the address

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm after some apache advice, I'm looking to find a way to make apache instance on the fly, thats the easy bit so i generate a `.cof` and a `crtl` and start the instance on say port 389.

So now if i go to `instance1.mysite:389` I'm given the site.

What I'm interested in is if is there a way I don't have to specify the port number to get to the site?

so I'm effectively generating virtual hosts that have there own apache configuration.

Any thoughts would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use name-based virtual hosts unless there's some reason you're trying to avoid them.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com 
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName other.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, it may just be that you used port 389 as an example, but in case you didn't I'd strongly recommend not using that port for web traffic. It's used by directory services like Active Directory and LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Debian derived distributions, you can create virtual hosts by creating configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory, making a symlink to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

After creating the configuration, you enter `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` command, which reloads Apache configuration, enabling the newly created virtual host.

This should achieve the same effect as creating new instances of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to configure Apache httpd for [dynamic virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html). If so, start reading...